# Mongoose: Streaming Aggregated JSON Data

Tags: mongoose, streaming, aggregate

As the title has indicated, I am using `Express` for my webapp.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

**API Controller**

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Doc = mongoose.model('Document');

var sendJSONresponse = function(res, status, content) {
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
};

// "/api/documents"
module.exports.listAllDocuments = function(req, res) {

  var stream = Doc.find().stream();
  stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(chunk));
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  }).on('end', function () {
    res.end();
  });

};
```

Instead of using `var stream = Doc.find().stream();`, I wish to make use of `aggregate()`.

Like `find()`, `aggregate()` is supposed to be a readable stream, right?

Yet, when I simply replaced `find()` with an `aggregate()` call, it does not seem to work.

It says TypeError: `Object #<Aggregate> has no method 'stream'`. What is an **alternative for streaming aggregated JSON data**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call [`cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor) on the `Aggregate` before executing it, the subsequent `exec()` returns a native cursor which you can then call [`stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream) on to stream the results.

```js
var stream = Doc.aggregate(pipeline).cursor().exec().stream();
stream.on('data', ...
```

Not exactly intuitive, but it worked when I tried it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it. @JohnnyHK. Another question: If my `aggregate()` call were to return a single document, is there no point to using `stream()`? From what I understand from using `stream()` with `find()`, the data is returned on a per-document basis. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: Right, it will stream as one result doc per data chunk. No way to change that AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on that, @JohnnyHK, :). By any chance, do you know of any way to make Express support data streaming in view rendering? >_<